# PowerShell: UnauthorizedAccessException (access is denied) when running Get-ChildItem

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012, powershell-4.0

I am running a deletion script via TeamCity and get the following error:

```
dir : Access is denied
At line:1 char:1
+ dir 'c:\inetpub\wwwroot\camping.info' -exclude docs,log,CampsiteImages*,_generat ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ChildItem], UnauthorizedAccessException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

In TeamCity I run a command line file. Within this file these commands are executed:

```
set POWERSHELLEXE=c:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
set FOLDER=c:\inetpub\wwwroot\folder

%POWERSHELLEXE% "dir '%FOLDER%' -exclude docs,log,CampsiteImages*,_generated,App_Code,App_Data,pics,style,temp,google*.html,app_offline.htm,robots.txt | del -Recurse -verbose"
```

The command sometimes runs without errors. But often it deletes a few folders before quitting with the above mentioned error. (Due to the `-verbose` flag we can see the deletions up to the error.) If there is an error it seems to stop at the same folder every time. We use the same script on different servers: on one server the script never has errors, on another server it rarely delivers an error - if it does than on a different folder. All servers have the same PowerShell and TeamCity versions.

**What could be the reason for this error?**

(I already tried to insert a waiting period before calling the delete command - that did not change anything.)

Comment: My first suspicion would be that a file in the directory is locked by another process.

Comment: @EBGreen: You mean it could be locked most of the times when the script is run, and sometimes not - in the rare cases the script does not quit with an error? I will try to exclude the folder from the deletion command.